# How does the Expand Singularity upgrade work?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Expand upgrade description is as follows: "Expand the Singularity field by 35% for 10 seconds". Singularity, however, doesn't last 10 seconds and the calculated radius next to the perk description remains the same. What does it really do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed expand the radius.

Comment: Any idea what the 10 seconds bit might be about? Does the radius return to normal if Singularity has been active for over 10 seconds?

Comment: basicly yeah. depends on how you specced your power.

Answer (score 0):

After the 10 seconds, the Singularity field goes to its default size.